# Gradle project naming conventions

Tags: gradle, naming-conventions

Maven `artifactId` should have lowercase letters. [Guide to naming conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) says:

> artifactId is the name of the jar without version. If you created it then you can choose whatever name you want with lowercase letters and no strange symbols.

Has Gradle something similar? How should Gradle projects be named?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if a Gradle project produces an archive, like a `jar`, the `archiveName` will be derived from the project name.
However this is something you can customise if you want, see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:archives).

Note that if you do not name your project, in the `settings.gradle`, the project name will default to the folder containing it.

And finally, if what you build is to be consumed by others, then I recommend sticking with the `artifactId` conventions.